# Is it possible to write a Visual Studio add-In using Java?

Tags: java, .net, visual-studio-2010

I need to write an add-in for Visual Studio 2010 and I want to use an existing API written in Java. Is there any way to use this API when developing the add-in, for example by writing it completely in Java (I assume, that's just a dream) or using some kind of wrapper language that can invoke methods from the API?

Thanks for your help.

Chris

Edit:
I found something in the interwebs: http://www.ikvm.net/index.html. 
Seems like there is a way to compile Java libraries into .NET. Regarding this option, I should be able to use the API I need, while writing the add-in in C#. Right? Or do I miss something here? Any concerns?

---

In fact, it is working - although indirectly. 
One can use the Java Native Interface (JNI)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/

Comment: There must be a way to run a generic external application.  If this is the case you can use it to run java.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write an addon for `Visual Studio` in Java, unfortunately. Here's [how you should do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb968855).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do so, because making an addon should follow Microsoft's architecture.